# Making ModelAttribute optional in Spring Controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a controller method defined as follows -

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/callMe")
public String myMethod(@ModelAttribute MyClass myObj, Model model) {
    //Do something
}
```

How can I make the above controller method to be called even when I do not passed the ModelAttribute myObj.

I do not want to create another controller without it and duplicate the functionality.

Comment: If you need one with and without the model and have the same functionality you might need to rethink (part) of your design. Also the model attribute is already optional, a new instance will be created (depending on how you initially created/stored the model attribute).

Comment: In our case we toggle features so it's helpful

Answer (score 3):

Model attribute is already optional. Even if you do not pass model attribute, myObj is created. So checking

```
if(myObj == null){
   //Do method1
}else{
  //Do method2
}
```

will not work.

Try this. create a Boolean in myClass like this

```
private Boolean isGotMyObj = false;
```

In your jsp which (submits model attribute) add a hidden input like this

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="isGotMyObj" />
```

then perform this in controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/callMe")
public String myMethod(@ModelAttribute MyClass myObj, Model model) {
    if (myObj.getIsGotMyObj()){
        //Got model attribute
        //Method 1
    }else{
        //Method 2
    }

    return "callme";
}
```