# Add optional parameters in @modelattribute in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working on spring mvc and I want to make some parameters in modelattribute as optional.
Ex. We can use @RequestMapping to set optional parameters by required=false. So I need something like this in @modelattribute. I don't want to use RequestParam because I have big list of parameters. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use ModelAttribute as the values will be populated by default values like 0 for integer, More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519927/making-modelattribute-optional-in-spring-controller-method)

Comment: Thanks for reply..but if it is optional then how can I make some fields required

Comment: Try using `@Valid ` with your model attribute. specify code here please in your OP. If you could do something like `@ModelAttribute("querier")
    public void populateIds (@RequestParam(value = "querier", required = false) String querier,
                             Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("querier", querier == null ? "quest" : querier);
    }`